# Read stencil texture in shader in WebGL2

Tags: fragment-shader, webgl2, stencil-buffer

I have a draw call which is updating the stencil buffer as a `DEPTH24_STENCIL8` texture, which I bound to my FBO as a depth-stencil attachment; this works fine. Now I wish to read back the final stencil values in another pass to do something with them. It's my understanding that you can bind such a texture to a shader and be able to sample the depth component... how would I go about reading the *stencil* component instead though?

Reading the ES 3.1 spec reveals in section 8.19 and 11.1.3.5 that there appears to be a special texture parameter `DEPTH_STENCIL_TEXTURE_MODE` which controls which of the depth and stencil components is returned in a texture lookup. But this parameter unfortunately appears to be absent from ES 3.0 and WebGL2, which would seem to lock the shader out from ever reading the stencil data.

How do I access the stencil component from my shader? I am using WebGL2. Thanks.

Comment: You can't directly AFAIK. You could read it indirectly by drawing to another texture and using the stencil test but you'd only get pass/fail (at least with a single draw).

Comment: @gman I was afraid that might be the case... I need exact values unfortunately, I guess I can do up to eight draws to extract each bit of the stencil and accumulate them into an R8 texture. Seems suboptimal but what can you do. I assume there is no way to directly "copy" the stencil buffer to a normal texture format? ES tries very hard to isolate color and depth-stencil attachments from one another.